# How to store table values in order

Tags: mysql

I created a table and inserted values into it but they are not storing in orderly manner.
The table looks like:
[image: data grid]

I can order them by using `ORDER BY` but it does not change them permanently. Is there a way to save them in orderly manner permanently.

**Clarification:** I don't want how they are stored internally, what I want is when ever I execute `select * from cricket;` the results to come sequentially. So that I don't want to use `ORDER BY` clause every time. Is there a way?

Comment: Why do you care what order the rows have in the permanent storage? By the way, the order that you see in the results of that select, may **not be** the order that the rows are stored.

Comment: Ok but I don't want how they are stored internally,what I want is when ever I execute select * from cricket; I want the results to come sequentially,So that I don't want to use ORDER BY clause every time.Is there a way????

Comment: If you don't want to use an order by clause then don't expect a specific order.

Comment: @Raghava `ALTER TABLE 'Cricket' ORDER BY 'sno';` will allow you to do a `select * from cricket` and get results returned ordered by sno 1,2,3,4,5,6   hope that helps as always, do a backup before making changes if you are new to working with DB.

Answer (score 3):

Without an ORDER BY clause, you have no guarantees as to the order the rows are presented to you, even if they 'look' ordered when you run a select.  Bullet 1 of this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: +1 The link applies only to SQL Server, but the answer applies to any SQL.

Answer (score 2):

[link] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

It suggests

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename' ORDER BY 'ColumnName';
```

Comment: That works for MyISAM, but not InnoDB.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you please provide the link which explains why it does not work with InnoDB

Comment: Well, there are probably a hundred links that explain that InnoDB data is ordered by the table's `PRIMARY KEY`.  Put another way, the PK is "clustered" with the data.  With MyISAM, the PK is just another index, stored in a separate BTree, thereby leaving the data to be shuffled as with that `ALTER`.